gdalwarp error 1 : Too many points failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds
GDAL ver: GDAL 3.9.3, released 2024-10-14
OS: Linux (Pop!_OS 22.04)
Input Raster dimensions  : 202500, 165000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
Input Raster resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
Input Raster extent      : 548522, 5498522, 1503304, 7578304  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
Input Raster coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
File link:               : https://daac.ornl.gov/ABOVE/guides/Boreal_AGB_Density_ICESat2.html
Desired output coord. ref  :  ESRI:102001 (NAD 1983 Albers Canada)
Console command:
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=aea +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs ESRI:102001 Duncanson1.tif Duncanson102001.tif

Error:

ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.

I have a merged version of the GeoTIFF dataset linked above and need to convert it to ESRI:102001 to add it to an analysis for a project I just inherited. Trying gdalwarp from the command line results in the error 1 being repeated over and over again. The same error occurs with QGIS and the terra package in R.
Here is the output of gdalinfo Duncanson1.tif:

I have read through a few gis stackexchange posts (including trying the answer from gdalwarp from epsg:4326 to epsg:3413; error: Too many points failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds) but that exact answer didn't work and I don't know enough about these projections to troubleshoot it myself.
How do I reproject this raster?

What does gdalinfo Duncanson1.tif show? Are all the source data within the area of use of ESRI:102001 https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102001/?

You may have lost the georeferencing during the merging. Add gdalinfo output and details about how you merged to your question.

Try this slightly modified command gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=aea +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs" -t_srs ESRI:102001 Duncanson1.tif Duncanson102001.tif

@user30184 I have added the output of gdalinfo to the question.

You have somehow odd corner coordinates. Some corners are far away from the valid area of ESRI:102001 WGS84 Bounds: -141.01, 38.21, -40.73, 86.46. Therefore the new "Point outside of projection domain" error. How did you make your mosaic? Are all the source images from Canada?

The source CRS is somehow inexact for the Proj library. The conversion from source to target can be tested with the projinfo utility:
projinfo -s "+proj=aea +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" -t ESRI:102001
source CRS string is not a CRS or a CoordinateMetadata

So Proj thinks that the given proj string is not a CRS or a CoordinateMetadata. To test what it is use projinfo again:
projinfo "+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
WKT2:2019 string:
CONVERSION["PROJ-based coordinate operation",
    METHOD["PROJ-based operation method: +proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"]]

Proj thinks that the string defines a conversion method instead of CRS. Proj will consider the string as CRS when a +type=crs parameter is added and then also gdalwarp should have success.
projinfo "+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=aea +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs

WKT2:2019 string:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["unknown",
            BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
                DATUM["Unknown based on GRS 1980 ellipsoid using towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                        ID["EPSG",7019]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8901]]],
            CONVERSION["unknown",
                METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
                    ID["EPSG",9822]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",40,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8821]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",180,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8822]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",50,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8823]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",70,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8824]],
                PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8826]],
                PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8827]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]],
                AXIS["(N)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["latitude",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["longitude",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation from unknown to WGS84",
        METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",
            ID["EPSG",9606]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8605]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8606]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8607]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8608]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8609]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8610]],
        PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,
            ID["EPSG",8611]]]]


Unfortunately, running the code: <<gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=aea +lat_0=40 +lon_0=180 +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs" -t_srs ESRI:102001 Duncanson1.tif Duncanson102001.tif>> still results in the following errors: ERROR 1: Point outside of projection domain.  ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds. Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 95080,10770,3068,2692, skipping.

You have solved the first problem anyway and GDAL understands the source CRS. Actually I believe that you could drop the whole -s_srs option because GDAL can read it correctly from the tiff file.  I must think about the projection domain a bit.
